# Mostrar texto enriquecido sin etiquetas MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

tengo una vista que muestra un objeto que viene de la base de datos, lo que pasa es que yo cuando creo ese objeto lo hago por medio de un editor de textos, y se guarda en la db con las etiquetas html correspondientes, mi problema es que cuando lo quiero mostrar a ese mismo objeto, la parte de "Contenido", se muestra tambien con las etiquetas, sin procesarlas. Alguien me explica como se hace para que se procesen las etiquetas y el texto se muestre como tiene que ser.

Uso Ckeditor como wysiwyg, ASP.NET MVC, C# y SQLServer

Este es mi modelo:

```
public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Titulo del articulo")]
    public string Titulo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Contenido del articulo")]
    [MaxLength(450)]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Contenido { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Descripcion del articulo")]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }

    public bool Activo { get; set; }
```

Este es mi Controller

```
public ActionResult Article(int id)
        {
            ArticleService articleService = new ArticleService();
            var model = articleService.GetArticle(id);
            return View(model);
        }
```

Y esta es la vista

```
    @model Entidades.Article
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Titulo;
}
<!-- Page Header -->
<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('img/post-bg.jpg')">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                <div class="post-heading">
                    <h1>@Model.Titulo</h1>
                    <h2 class="subheading">@Model.Descripcion</h2>
                    <span class="meta">
                        Escrito por
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Blog")">Inicio</a>
                        @Model.FechaCreacion.ToShortDateString()
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- Post Content -->
<article>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
               <p>@Model.Contenido</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
<hr>
```

Bueno desde ya gracias.

Comment: Solo como referencia podrias mirar [ask] . También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes renderizar tu texto con:

```
@Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(Model.yourEncodedHtmlFromYourDatabase))
```

Comment: Reformula tu pregunta puedes agregar casos o ejemplos porque le falta claridad al problema

Comment: Las respuestas que son solo codigo sin ninguna explicacion se consideran de baja calidad. Mira por favor [answer]. Podrias explicar que hace esto?

Comment: @KodiakMx La explicacion no es para mi. Tu respuesta fue reportada como de baja calidad por ser solo una linea de codigo. Donde tiene que poner eso? que es lo que tiene que poner en cada lugar? Se pide que las respuestas tengan un minimo de contenido.